# Can't create new OneNote notebook: "Create" button is disabled

Tags: office365, microsoft-onenote

I'm a new OneNote user. I'm trying to create my first notebook. However, the "Create" button is disabled. See screencap below.

[image: OneNote's New Notebook dialog]

P.S.
The "Where" menu is empty.

---

OS: macOS High Sierra, version 10.13
Application: Microsoft OneNote for Mac, version 15.39 (171010)

Comment: And what happens if you tell it **where** to create the new notebook? Does the Create button then become enabled?

Comment: @DavidPostill: The **where** menu is empty.

Comment: [Can't create new notebook in Microsoft OneNote for Mac](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/150466)

Comment: Which answer worked?

Comment: @DavidPostill: [This one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211612/136773), sort of. More precisely, what I did was to sign in to my Microsoft account via OneNote's Sign In... menu option (on a Mac, it's on the OneNote menu), and then all was good.

Comment: You should answer this question then with what you did :)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Done.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a new notebook, you must select an option from the **Where** menu. So your question should have been: "Why is my **Where** menu empty?" The reason your **Where** menu is empty is that you're not signed-in to your Microsoft account. You can sign-in to your Microsoft account using the **Sign in...** item on the **OneNote** menu (see screen cap below).

[image: The "Sign in..." menu item]